# Python writing to a csv file produces extra space in excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

Hello I currently have the following function for my write method that behaves in the correct way with one error. The error being each output of the csv document opened in excel has a blank row in between rows with data. How could I fix the following function.

```
def fileWrite(output,failed_list_csv_out):
    fileToWrite = open('SampleId_ExecutionId.csv','w') 
    with fileToWrite:
        writer = csv.writer(fileToWrite)
        writer.writerows(output)
        writer.writerows(failed_list_csv_out)
```

Comment: can you please share some sample data with us e.g what is output data, faield_list_csv_out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the method rstrip to remove the newline character from the data.

```
>>> 'some string\n'.rstrip()
'some string
```

Comment: I think the question was misunderstood. I am already stripping everything that is being read in of with rstrip(), lstrip, strip(\r,\n,\t). The current issue is that when I go to write and this only happens on windows computers as I have written the code on the mac it writes an extra blank row of data between the fields of data.